# Disable Screen Recording prompt from bluetooth game controller (maybe Big Sur only?)

Tags: bluetooth, screen-recording

I have an 8bitdo bluetooth controller that I use to play games on my Macbook with the latest Big Sur. I think since the upgrade to Big Sur, sometimes when I am using the controller Mac OS will break fullscreen to pop up a series of confirmations about whether I want to allow different apps that are currently running to record the screen. I have to click through each one to get back to my game. This happens whether I'm actually playing a game/have Steam open, or if I am just sitting on at the desktop. It happens when I have the controller connected to the Mac and press Select and Start at the same time, or sometimes Select and the Special/Meta button. It doesn't happen every time I press these combinations, I do have to press them multiple times to get the issue to repeat, but it happens very often.

Is there any way to disable screen recording or this "shortcut" or whatever it is? I almost never want to record my screen, so turning off the feature would be fine if possible.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an updated answer for MacOS Ventura.

First of all, by default, it's a double press of the "select" button on your joypad that triggers the prompt, which is easily done accidentally.

To avoid this, we're going to create a new "controller profile" where that feature is disabled. Sadly, you cannot edit the default profile.

So, with your 8BitDo controller connected via Bluetooth, open System Settings and scroll down to the section called "Game Controllers".

Under Profiles, click the + button to create a new profile.

[image: Create New Profile]

Give the profile a name like "Share Gestures Disabled" and then scroll down to the very bottom of the page to the "Share Gestures" section.  Set all gestures to "Off" and then click "Done" to save.

[image: Share Gestures Disabled]

Back in the Game Controllers section, click on your 8BitDo controller and in the bit that says "Use profile" choose the "Share Gestures Disabled" profile instead of "Default".  Click "Done" to save that.

[image: New profile selected]

Comment: Thanks for this! It made the controller usable for me at last.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Bluetooth section of your System Preferences app while the controller is connected. There should be an "Options" button next to it. This brings up the following panel for my 8bitdo:
[image: controller button mapping panel]

Changing both of the mappings for the Share button to "Off" did the trick for me.

Comment: It seems that this is only available in Monterey though